# Divide Total Values Into Three Parts - Bin Packing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to divide the second column into three parts, such that they are equally divided, but if the total values is not divisible by three, the case is that that first part is higher or equal than the second part, and the second part is higher or equal than the third part.

Here is the sample of my table:

```
  ID   |  Values  
-------------------------
   1       1
   2       1
   3       2
   4       1
   5       2
   6       1
   7       3
```

My expected output should be (The ID column here is just a row number):

```
  ID   |  Divided
-------------------------
   1       3
   2       3
   3       1
```

As you can see, the total values is 11 if you add them all. So if we divide it by 3, the resulting values are 4, 4, and 3. So I will just count it to get the expected output:

```
(1, 1, 2) = 3, 
next is (1, 2, 1) = 3, 
and the last is (3) = 1.
```

Any idea how will I approach this problem? I have divided them by three but counting them to get the specific business logic is difficult:

```
select @intSum = SUM(Values) / 3 from @table
```

I am trying to this on stored procedure.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I apologized for that. I corrected my description :)

Comment: Does the ID column in the output mean anything other than a row number?  Can you say any more about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes that is just a row number. The result should always be three parts so it doesn't matter on what values on the result of ID column. @Grax

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: I am using 2016. @Jayvee

Comment: And what happens if the values are 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50?

Comment: This is a bin-packing problem.  It is a bit challenging to solve in general and SQL is not the right tool for an exact solution.

Comment: There wouldn't any table with those data, but it can be (50, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) and the answer would be 1, 3, 3. @AlexanderMP

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the term bin-packing problem atleast I have an idea what kind of problem is this. @GordonLinoff

Comment: What do you mean there wouldn't? What is the restriction on the data? Can we have 1, 1, 2? Can we have 1, 2, 3?